# instead of creating a new word when playing again it is adding it to the previous one, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When the user chooses to play again the code outputs the new hangman word appended to the last one they tried to guess.
I think an important function that causes the mistake is the play_again() but I don't know what to do about it.
instead of restarting the word and outputting the new word for the new game, it just appends it to the old one and adds up.

```
import random
import sys

word_list = ['zebra',  'memory', 'desktop', 'earthquake']

guess_word = []
secret_word = random.choice(word_list)
lenght_word = len(secret_word)
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
letter_storage = []
word_list = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 4 and len(x) <= 7, 
word_list))

def main():
    play_function()
    change()
    guessing()
    play_again()

def play_function():
    print('Welcome to HANGMAN by @PonyKillerMX')

    while True:
        game_choice = str(input('Do you want to play? ')).lower()
        if game_choice in ['yes', 'y']:
            print("yes")
            break
        elif game_choice in ['no', 'n']:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print('Please answer only Yes/y or No/n')
            continue

def change():
    for character in secret_word:
        guess_word.append("-")
    print('-- The word you need to guess has', lenght_word, 'characters --')
    print(guess_word)

def guessing():
    guess_taken = 0
    while guess_taken <= 10:
        guess = input('Pick a letter: ').lower()
        if guess in ['exit', 'quit']:
            # User can exit the game whenever he desires
            print('Thank you for playing')
            sys.exit()
        elif not guess in alphabet:
            print('Enter a letter from a-z')
        elif guess in letter_storage:
            print('You have already guessed that letter')
        else:
            letter_storage.append(guess)
            # Store all the guesses to know when its repeated
            if guess in secret_word:
                guess_taken += 1
                print('You guessed correctly!')
                print('Guesses remaining:', (10 - 
                int(guess_taken)))
                for x in range(0, lenght_word):
                    if secret_word[x] == guess:
                        guess_word[x] = guess
                        print(guess_word)

            elif not guess in secret_word:
                guess_taken += 1
                print('Missed atempt')
                print('Guesses remaining:', (10 - 
                int(guess_taken)))
                print(guess_word)

    if guess_taken > 9:
        print('The secret word was:', secret_word)
        print('Thank you for playing')

def play_again():
    # Lose or win the game you can still choose to play again
    again = str(input('Do you want to play again? ')).lower()
    if again in ['yes', 'y']:
        break
        main()
    elif again in ['no', 'n']:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('Please answer only Yes/y or No/n')


main()
```

Comment: Didn't figure out your error, but what I noted is how you call `main`. You should avoid that, because if a player plays many rounds, the stack is filled because of the recursive calls you do (`main->play_again->main->...`). I'd rather put the query "Do you want to play again?" in a loop. Either `while True:` or `while again in ...:`. In the second case you could initialize `again='yes'` just before you enter the loop. Then the `break` in `play_again` seems very strange to me. Usually breaks are placed within a loop, but there is no loop. What did you intend to do with that?

Comment: Btw, you should also avoid the `sys.exit()`. In some cases it is needed, but whenever there is a way to avoid it, its most likely the better choice and here with a loop you really can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recreate `guess_word` and/or `secret_word` before starting over. One way to do that would be to **move** those statements to the beginning of the `change` function.

```
def change():
    guess_word = []
    secret_word = random.choice(word_list)
    for character in secret_word:
        guess_word.append("-")
    print('-- The word you need to guess has', lenght_word, 'characters --')
    print(guess_word)
```

---

OR you could **add** them to the beginning of `play_again()`.

Comment: I think that's it. I just recognized it, but I think he could improve the quality of his code in some other places.

Answer (score 0):

You're using recursion(call `main()` from `main()`), which is not really needed, but it's not critical. Your problem is in this loop:

```
for character in secret_word:
    guess_word.append("-")
```

After first execution you don't clean `guess_word` variable. Simplest solution:

```
guess_word = ""
for character in secret_word:
    guess_word.append("-")
```

You can replace this loop (which also fixes your problem):

```
guess_word = "-" * len(secret_word)
```

Comment: But then if I put guess_word() inside the function I can't use it again when I need it later in the code and now it prints out: name 'guess_word' is not defined

Comment: @EmilioAndere, in your code `guess_word` is string variable, not a function.. Your word stored in variable `secret_word`, you're using `guess_word` as buffer for showing position of letters player guessed. I don't clearly understand where's a problem..